# Highlight text color problem in MySQL Workbench 8.0.13 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, colors, text-editor, mysql-workbench

I started using Workbench to connect with DDBB and making some queries but when I select some text to only execute that part, the text and background color are the same.

I read something about code_editor.xml... but also that these colors can not be changed modifying that file and depends on the OS ( https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,665348,665348#msg-665348 ).

The color changes if I use Adwaita-dark but the problem is still there.
I tried with two different shell themes using Tweak Tools, too.

I also read about modifying some files located in /usr/themes/ to change the color, but the color that appears in those files as selected text background doesn't match with the Workbench's one (it's orange).

We (college stuff) are using for the moment a VM with Ubuntu 16.04 and Workbench 6.3.10 to avoid this problem...

[Workbench and Adwaita or Ambiance...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVd98.png)

[... with selected text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj4tw.png)

[Selected text in Adwaita-dark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tsJP.png)

[Ubuntu 16.04 and Workbench 6.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqaiH.png)

Comment: ON Mac [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53861198/1358777) seems to fix the problem. Still finding a way to fix my kubuntu install

Comment: Seems issue is related to dark themes on plasma. Couldn't find a fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last days there was an update for Workbench package and now it's solved, at least for the Ubuntu and Gnome of the OP.

[Problem solved updating Workbench to 18.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOiPj.png)